# Should I open ICMP connections on my NAT instance security group in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, nat, icmp

I have a VPC on aws with a private subnet and a public subnet. I use the documented setup for this scenario, with a NAT instance.

It is advised on this link [docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html)
to open TCP ports 22 the world; and 80 and 443 to the VPC. After trying to test the connectivity using ping from an instance on the private network, i realised that ping used icmp protocol, which is completely shutdown by this security group configuration. In fact, i can wget just fine.
I have very little knowledge of what happens with ICMP, so my question is the following: Is it ok to block all ICMP connection to my NAT instance?

As a secondary question, I also should ask whether it is problematic to open all ICMP connection to my NAT instance.

Comment: Yes you can always block ICMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can always block ICMP. It won't affect anything.

Also it's not safe to keep the port 22 open for the world. You can open port 22 for your home ip only when you need it.

Comment: I have dynamic ip so that would be a problem not to open ssh to the world...

Comment: You can add IP of that time , do your work. Next time repeat the same . Do you think it's very inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ICMP, unless you specifically want to leave it open for connectivity debugging.

Additionally, unless you have very specific needs, I would strongly advise to use AWS NAT Gateways instead of NAT instances: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html